# How fast may be double click?

Tags: javascript, double-click

I have the following JS code

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  ...
  buttons: {
    OK: function() {
      callAjax({"some":"param"});
      $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    }
  }
});

var ajaxBatch = [];

function callAjax(cmd) {
  ajaxBatch.push(cmd);
  if (ajaxBatch.length == 1)
    setTimeout(ajaxItself, 1);
}

function ajaxItself() {
  ajaxBatch.push({"minor":"data"});
  $.post('url', { msg: JSON.stringify(ajaxBatch) });
  ajaxBatch = [];
}
```

Theoretically I should always got `[{"some":"param"},{"minor":"data"}]`.

But frequently I got error log entries on wrong requests with `[{"some":"param"},{"some":"param"},{"minor":"data"}]` there.

How such things may happen? Do the A4 mice with their 2x button make sense here, or what?

BTW, I can't reproduce the situation, I just see it in logs. And User-Agent is not bounded to particular browser there either.

Comment: A4 mice? 2x button? Huh? What's the purpose of the timeout? That leaves a 1ms window for additional clicks to be registered.

Comment: The purpose is to gather several commands in one query. But the dialog with event-generating button is to be closed right after the first `push()`.

Comment: Then why a 1ms timeout? If you want to register multiple pushes, 1ms window is VERY short.

Comment: I want to gather all the commands within one tick. I don't need to wait for user input or timers.

Comment: Btw, `setTimeout(fn, 0)` will work the same. But `1` looks there more obviously to me.

Comment: But you're going to lose any clicks The first click pushes 1 value, which triggers the timeout. When the ajax call returns, it'll delete the 'ajaxBatch' array and kill any ADDITIONAL entries that may have been added in between the time the ajax call started and its response came back. Nasty race condition.

Comment: Just a heads up, you're not actually doing a 1ms timeout. Most modern browsers limit it to 4ms - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Nope. `ajaxBatch` is being cleared right after the moment when AJAX query has been sent (not on response!). It happen in the same tick, there can't be any calls between these operators (because JS is single-threaded). This solution works fine to me for two years. When there're no click handlers, there're no problems absolutely.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I know. It just means "next tick". It may happen after 200ms and more if the CPU is slow enough. `postMessage` will work faster on fast CPUs, but 1ms timeout plays well here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser might have queued up more than 1 click event, so whether or not the button is visible for them to keep clicking, the events were already set in motion.

Maybe set a flag in your `OK:` function

```
if (!dialogIsClosed) {
      callAjax({"some":"param"});
      $('#dialog').dialog('close');
      dialogIsClosed = true;
}
```

I would imagine a browser would choose processing an item from the event queue over processing an item from the setTimeout queue.

Comment: Thanks. This is a workaround, of course. But I would like to find the reason, if it possible. Though, your answer makes me think that browser may hung up while OS is sending two click events from separate user clicks.

Comment: It may or may not be revealing to log the milliseconds of the click event. Hopefully it's resolution is great enough for you to see a difference.